# Переход на https. Небезопасное пассивное содержимое

Tags: https

Ситауция следующая. 
Поддержка хостинга моего сайта выполнила запрос по переводу на протокол https. 
При этом в строке браузера вижу желтый треугольник с восклицательным знаком (предупреждение **о незащищенном соединении: Части этой страницы (такие как изображения) не защищены**.

Сейчас я дорабатываю сайт, в т.ч. меняю ссылки http на https. Техподдержка сообщила, что после этого ошибка пропадет
 Но некоторые библиотеки подключаются по старому протоколу, некоторые счетчики также работают по http. **Консоль говорит именно о счетчиках сторонних сервисов.** Насколько их наличие на сайте небезопасно?

Как поступить в такой ситуации? Можно ли как-то решить эту проблему без удаления проблемного счетчика?

С одной стороны, мне бы хотелось, чтобы незащищенного соединения не было, т.к. я планирую сделать личные кабинеты пользователей с закрытыми данными. С другой стороны, участие в рейтинге, чей счетчик дает такую ошибку, приносит целевые переходы.

Спасибо!

Comment: Вы или переводите счетчик на https, или удаляете его. Других вариантов нет.

Comment: Спасибо! Удалила. Если оформите ответ, а не комментарий, я смогу выбрать его лучшим.

Comment: Попросите авторов этого счётчика предоставить https версию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По факту если ваши счетчики со сторонних сайтов, на вашу безопасность сайта, это никак не влияет, так как это сторонний сервис. И можете их оставить, просто будет постоянно выводится что защищено не полностью, но данные ваши будут зашифрованы) А вообще для сайта достаточно 2 счетчиков, Yandex метрика и Google analytics, остальные бесполезны!

Answer (score 2):

Нельзя обхитрить браузер и оставить незащищенный контент без предупреждения. Так что вам или переводить счетчик на `https` или удалять его.

Comment: Можно обхитрить, пустив контент через https-прокси. Правда, счётчик после этого станет бесполезен)

Comment: @andreymal это называется обхитрить самого себя)